# Unable to find Huffman table

Tags: image-processing, compression, jpeg, huffman-code, image-compression

I want to compress BMP images into a JPEG bitstream. But I couldn't find a Huffman table in .csv or .txt format anywhere on the internet so that I can read that file directly into my code. So I am unable to find the corresponding Huffman codes for (run-length, size) pairs. Can someone provide the link to this table or any information regarding where to find this?

Comment: There's much more to jpeg compression than just Huffman encoding. My recommendation would be to use an existing library, but if you insist on doing this from scratch the first step would be to google `jpeg specification`.

Comment: Actually this is for a course project and I have to do everything from scratch. And the only thing I need to complete the project now is this table.

Comment: Did you learn about Huffman encoding?